# bad power supply or gpu? limiting gpu power allows machine to _not_ crash

Tags: power-supply, crash, gpu

I have a linux machine with an nvidia 1080 gpu.
The machine was always crashing when running deep learning training job.

I learned about the power limit flags to the driver

```
  nvidia-smi --power-limit=120
  nvidia-smi -pm 1           // make persistant
```

Tried this and    no more crashes!

My question: *does this mean the power supply is bad? Or the GPU?*  Or?

Forgive, I do not immediately recall the specs of the power supply, 
but it is large and was assured that it would be enough to power the gpu or even two gpus. 
I believe the *choice* of power supply is not thie issue.

Notes:

1. A memory check on the machine did not show problem.
2. I post the question here because this post recommends this community https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299370/stack-exchange-site-for-pc-hardware-questions
3. Very novice about hardware, please be gentle.

Comment: Have you checked thermal issues? Check GPU (and CPU) temps, and try an additional fan, after removing the power restriction.

Comment: You did not specify the CPU used, so please run `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name" && sudo lshw | grep -A5 "Moth" && lshw | grep product` in a terminal, then copy the results, click [edit] and put that into your question. Don't use Add Comment as it will lose all formatting.